# How to add legend to kendo stock chart using multiple series?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

we have a page which has stock charts in it, Aside from the Stock chart, in the same page we have also grids also here in Kendo StockChart legend is not displaying dynamically.
   So i had tried with using multiple series in code:
            But while run this code legend values are repeating,how solve this issue

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var db = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data : data,
        group: {
            field: "studentmarks"
        }
    });

    db.read();

    $("#Chart").kendoStockChart({
        theme     : $(document).data("kendoSkin") || "silver",
        dataSource: db,
        aggregate : [
            { field: "ID", aggregate: "aggregate", line: "line"}
        ],


        title         : {
            text: "CDR"
        },
        dateField     : "time",
        repeat        : false,
        legend        : {
            position: "right"
        },
        chartArea     : {
            background: ""
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            type: "line", field: "ID"
        },

        series   : [
            {
                name           : "iad",
                data           : data,
                filter         : "studentmarks",
                color          : "#FC0505",
                width          : 2,
                line           : "line",
                aggregate      : "aggregate",
                visibleInLegend: "studentmarks",

                markers: {
                    visible: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format : "{0}%"
                }
            },
            {
                name   : "pht",
                filter : "studentmarks",
                data   : data,
                axis   : "",
                color  : "#2605FC",
                width  : 2,
                line   : "line",
                markers: {
                    visible: true
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format : "{0}"
                }
            },
            {
                name   : "phone",
                filter : "studentmarks",
                data   : data,
                axis   : "",
                color  : "#ED9AA5",
                width  : 2,
                line   : "line",
                markers: {
                    visible: true
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format : "{0}%"
                }

            },
            {
                name   : "cbs",
                filter : "studentmarks",
                data   : data,
                axis   : "",
                color  : "#9AA5ED",
                visible: true,
                opacity: .4,
                width  : 2,
                line   : "line",
                markers: {
                    visible: true
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format : "{0}%"
                }
            }
        ],
        valueAxis: [
            {
                title    : { text: "" },
                name     : "mos",
                majorUnit: 0.5,
                max      : 5.0,
                min      : 0
            },
            {
                name     : "ink",
                title    : { text: "" },
                min      : 0,
                max      : 6727.14,
                majorUnit: 1000,
                minorUnit: 500
            }
        ],


        navigator: {
            series: {
                type     : "area",
                color    : "red",
                field    : "time",
                stack    : "true",
                value    : "studentmarks",
                data     : data,
                aggregate: "min",
                name     : "sai",
                select   : {
                    from: "2009-01-01 17:08:04",
                    to  : "2013-12-24 20:30:26"
                },
                labels   : { color: "green", visible: false },
                tooltip  : { background: "green", format: "{0}", color: "white", visible: true }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: How does your `data` look like?
Did you realize that `group` definition, defines `field` twice (first as `"ID"` and the as `"studentmarks"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off the Legend and create your own. You'll have more flexibility in doing exactly what you want.